# Akeneo 2.2.5: No JobInstance found with code "add_to_existing_product_model"

Tags: akeneo

*Since the forum at akeneo.com is locked down, I posted my question here.*

When I try to add Produkts to a Product-Model via mass-edit, I get the following error message:

`No JobInstance found with code "add_to_existing_product_model"`

```
[2018-06-19 19:39:31] request.INFO: Matched route "pim_enrich_mass_edit_rest_launch". {"route":"pim_enrich_mass_edit_rest_launch","route_parameters":{"_controller":"pim_enrich.controller.rest.mass_edit:launchAction","_route":"pim_enrich_mass_edit_rest_launch"},"request_uri":"http://pim.eu-trading.eu/rest/mass_edit/","method":"POST"} []
[2018-06-19 19:39:32] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Translation\Exception\NotFoundResourceException: "No JobInstance found with code "add_to_existing_product_model"" at ./vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/MassEditAction/OperationJobLauncher.php line 59 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\Exception\\NotFoundResourceException(code: 0): No JobInstance found with code \"add_to_existing_product_model\" at ./vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/MassEditAction/OperationJobLauncher.php:59)"} []
```

I get this error with the latest version of Akeneo 2 (v2.2.5). The product model was created manually, the products to be associated with the model came through the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error looks like a missing job in the database. Did you run all the doctrine migrations?

To do so you need to launch this command:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=prod
```

If you already launched the migrations and they failed, you can install a clean 2.2.5 PIM elsewhere and dump the job instance table to be able to add the missing jobs. Here is the list of the jobs to add or update in 2.2:

```
- add_association
- move_to_category
- add_to_category
- remove_from_category
- add_to_existing_product_model
- compute_family_variant_structure_changes
- compute_completeness_of_products_family
- add_attribute_value
- delete_products_and_product_models
```

Comment: Although the migration table was empty, the relevant migrations have palpably already been executed. Almost all migrations failed because they wanted to make changes to the tables that were already as they should be. After invoking migrations the second time, a message "No migrations to execute" appeared. The original error remains. Here is a [screenshot](https://snag.gy/V4KhJ7.jpg) of the `akeneo_batch_job_instance`-table.

Comment: Ok, I updated the original answer. If your migration didn't went well, you should really investigate and retry them. It's not normal at all and should be fixed if you don't want to have problems in the future.

Comment: I've added the missing entry by hand and now everything works as expected!